# what's a good/proper way to check whether a Web API is available?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an application which gets data from an API:

```
string jDoc = webclient.DownloadString(url);
```

Before I make this call, however, I need to make sure the API is available.

How would I go about doing this?

Should I just use a `TRY/CATCH` block or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If you are referring to an API provided by the web server that you are connecting to, then I don't think you have much choice - you'll have to catch errors from the webClient.  I find it hard to grok why you would connect to a site that isn't providing the API, tho.

Comment: I see. Well, the API is on the same server as the web application. I have the 2 separate... (first time creating APIs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Web API is like any other web page, so this comes down to "How do I see if a webpage is responding?"

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200.aspx), sure, just use `try/catch`.  If there's a `WebException`, and you're sure the address is valid, then there was some issue in making your query.  You can check the `Response` and `Status` properties of the WebException to learn more.